# What PCL profile (or .NET standard version) is the common denominator of my Nuget Packages?

Tags: xamarin.ios, nuget, portable-class-library, .net-standard, visual-studio-mac

I want to upgrade a PCL project to a newer version, and am having trouble reconciling the Nuget PCL versions.  I need a tool, or manual instructions to help me identify what PCL version would work for all of them.

Right now I'm trying to update an older version [Splat](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Splat/) in a Xamarin forms application, which is PCL Profile 111.

I downloaded the Nuget file, unzipped it and saw these file contents.  I'm not sure how to interpret this, but using .NET standard 1.5 didn't work at all.  Perhaps that means I need to use the specific version listed there?

[image]

Comment: "using .NET standard 1.5 didn't work at all" is weird. If your project is .NET Standard 1.5, then NuGet should use the .NET Standard 1.1 assembly from that package.

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to do. Splat 2.0.0 installs fine for me into a PCL project that targets profile 111. It also installs fine for me into a PCL project that was converted to target .NET Standard 1.5 via the project options - Build - General - Target framework. What does 'didn't work at all' mean specifically - what error message do you see?